# QThread Barrier mechanizm in Cpp

Tags: qt, qthread, barrier

How can I define a barrier point In a Qthread run() method for synchronization.
My run method code consists of two stages, and all of the threads must reach the end of the first stage before they can pass the second stage.

```
void ThreadClass::run()
{

    barrier// All of the thread must reach this point before passing below the line

}
```

Comment: I'm using thread pool and starting 4 thread. Every thread do same operation on special part of array list. And it must wait for all other threads came same point. Then every thread do other operations on them special part of array list.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head ::

1 : Create a mutex and then lock it in your main() before creating the thread pool. Create the thread pool, let them run, your barrier should read like this.

```
perThreadReachedThisPointFlag = 1;
mutexCreatedByMain.lock();
mutexCreatedByMain.unlock();
```

In your main(), monitor the thread pool. If you observe (do not forget the memory fences) that all the threads in the pool have set the perThreadReachedThisPointFlag, then execute mutexCreatedByMain.unlock(); on your main().

All the threads were waiting to lock the mentioned mutex, then you let them go. All of them will lock then unlock the mutex.

2 : Another way would be using conditionVariable and conditionSignal functionality of pthread but I do not know a replacement for Windows.